# The last digit of a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove that if $n$ a natural number then $n^2$ never ends with the digits 2,3,7,8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $n$ end with $0$ then $n^2$ end with $0$ too.
Now assume that end with $1$ then $n^2$ end with $1$ too.
You can repeat this for each digit and newer meet $2,3,7,8$.

Answer (score 2):

Every natural number can be represented as :$$n=10k+r$$where $k$ is an integer and $r$ is the remainder $(0,1,...,9)$  , now look at $$(10k+r)^{2}=100k^{2}+20kr+r^{2}$$ so the last digit of this number must be the same as the last digit of $r^{2}$ and a simple check for all the possible $r$ will give you all the possibilities for the last digit of a square number.

Answer (score 0):

They do not end with those numbers because they end with $$0^2\equiv0\\1^2\equiv1\\2^2\equiv4\\3^2\equiv9\\4^2\equiv6\\5^2\equiv5\\6^2\equiv6\\7^2\equiv9\\8^2\equiv4\\9^2\equiv1$$hence $\{0,1,4,5,6,9\}$